# SQL Server GenRepeatingChars?

Tags: sql-server-2005

On my Sql Server Query i have found a query where there is a statement.

" dbo.GenRepeatingChars('0',8) AABBCCDD "

here AABBCCDD is may table column name. but What is the use of GenRepeatingChars? Please can any one brief me in details...

Comment: Looks like a user-defined function. Do you have access to the source code?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without looking at the function, but repeating character masking sometimes used as obfuscation method. Provide the GenRepeatingChars function to better understand the purpose.

Comment: here is the full query:

select  dbo.GenRepeatingChars('0',8) MANFACDT
 , dbo.GenRepeatingChars('0',12) DUE4RCVRY
 , dbo.GenRepeatingChars('0',12) RCVRYCUR

from wrkInstallmentLoans